# RSpec can't find haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, haml

I'm writing a RoR app, and the automatically generated tests fail because of the following:

```
11) Sources GET /sources works! (now write some real specs)
     Failure/Error: get sources_path
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sources/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/brian.hicks/Dropbox/code/incremental/incremental/app/views"
         * "/Users/brian.hicks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@incremental/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
     # ./app/controllers/sources_controller.rb:11:in `index'
     # ./spec/requests/sources_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm using the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'haml-rails', '>= 0.3.4'
gem 'rspec-rail', '>= 2.8.1'
```

Is there a specific config value I need to set somewhere to use the `:haml` handler as well as the rest of them?

By request, here's `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
    activesupport (3.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bson (1.6.2)
    bson_ext (1.6.2)
      bson (~> 1.6.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    database_cleaner (0.7.2)
    devise (2.0.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (3.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (3.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    haml (3.1.4)
    haml-rails (0.3.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      haml (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    heroku (2.24.1)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.6)
    launchy (2.1.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    libwebsocket (0.1.3)
      addressable
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.18)
    mongo (1.6.2)
      bson (~> 1.6.2)
    mongoid (2.4.8)
      activemodel (~> 3.1)
      mongo (~> 1.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    mongoid-rspec (1.4.4)
      mongoid (~> 2.0)
      rspec (~> 2)
    multi_json (1.2.0)
    netrc (0.7.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    orm_adapter (0.0.7)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    quiet_assets (1.0.0)
      rails (~> 3.1)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activerecord (= 3.2.3)
      activeresource (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.3)
    railties (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.9.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.9.0)
    rspec-core (2.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.9.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.7)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.21.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
      libwebsocket (~> 0.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    simple_form (2.0.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bson_ext (>= 1.3.1)
  cancan
  capybara (>= 1.1.2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  database_cleaner (>= 0.7.1)
  devise (>= 2.0.0)
  factory_girl_rails (>= 1.6.0)
  haml-rails (>= 0.3.4)
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  launchy (>= 2.0.5)
  mongoid (>= 2.4.3)
  mongoid-rspec (>= 1.4.4)
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 3.2.3)
  rspec-rails (>= 2.8.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  simple_form
  thin
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: I assume you renamed your `views/sources/index.html.erb` to `views/sources/index.html.haml`?

Comment: Actually, the haml-rails gem generated those haml files for me. I customized them, and they work with webrick serving. I don't think I ever had erb files there.

Comment: Strange. There shouldn't be any additional config for haml to work. Did you restart the Rails server? Are you using Spork with Rspec and was it restarted? Or are you using Guard with Rspec and was it restarted?

Comment: restart: yes, but why would that have helped for tests? spork: no. guard: no. If it helps, running with `rake` and `rspec` both result in the same thing.

Comment: You're right on the restart, I didn't think that one through. Can you post your `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: I've edited the question to have `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` looks fine - not sure if I have any more suggestions for this one. Good luck finding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

***update:** I saw a similar question (which I now cannot find :}) which suggested adding the text*

```
require "haml"
```

*to the config/test.rb settings, and that did the trick for me.  So I don't need to specify template handlers in references such as partials or layout any longer and everything works.*

I'm getting the same issue with Rails 3.2.2, Cucumber 1.10 and rspec-rails 2.8.0.

The following workaround gets me around the problem: Any place I reference a HAML-based partial, I use the fully-qualified name of the template.  So for example to reference my admin layout in the admin section of my site I entered 'layout admin.html.haml' instead of 'layout admin'.  Likewise for partials I used the full name of my haml files instead of just the name without any suffixes, and this makes RSpec and my tests happy,

Now, I *shouldn't* have to do this, and I realize that passing a template handler in the template name is (or is going to be) deprecated per [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/rubyonrails-talk/121fjdnjvm/rails-deprecation-warning-passing-a-template-handler-in-the-template-name-is-deprecated-rspec-haml), but this does unblock my tests and works in production until I find the right solution.

I've never had to specify the template handler in references before, I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I added HAML support to my site after it was created, but I haven't found the config setting that I'd guess I'm missing.

Good luck! Michael